# Reblog a post when user repost from another user timeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, activerecord-relation

I need to enable a functionality like tumblr or similar blogs, where the the user can see the original poster (creator) and the user who reposted.

e.g. User A create a post1, User B 'repost' post1, User C discovered post1, because he follow user B or whatever. So user C must see 'post1, posted by User A, reposted by UserB... and so on if user C repost post1.

Currently user can like a micropost, but I also need to be able to 're_like' a micropost.

Firs I need to know the post belongs to reposter user.

I've seen some approach where we have different urls depending on user who reposted.

original ./post/1/
reposted ./post/1/reposted/18   (I guess 18 is repost_id or reposter_id)

```
My Models:

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :likes
  has_many :liked_posts, through: :likes, source: :micropost, dependent: :destroy

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :micropost
  has_many :likes

class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes
  has_many :liking_users, through: :likes, source: :user, dependent: :destroy
```

Rails 4.2.0

Comment: How about creating a new model called something like "repost" and add its association? then when someone reposts a micropost a new record is created in reports table "original_user_id: 1, user_id: 2, original_post_id: 1, repost_id: 2", that way you can call micropost.reposts and get all the reposts of that micropost. what do you think?

Comment: @saadlulu I don't think so, because we are replicating content. I though a similar way, but creating a new field in 'Like' table called 'liked_from_user_id'

Comment: @the-thin-man  Your help is appreciated!!

Comment: @konstantin-gredeskoul Can you please suggest me a way to get the user_id where I reposted?

Comment: @konstantin-gredeskoul if you dont want add duplicates then if the original poster removes his post, any reposts will also be removed